In BigQuery, why did it accept this one syntax over the other one?
So, I created a table within a dataset in BigQuery Studio of movie data which includes release dates, movie titles, Wikipedia website links, etc. and I uploaded the table as a .csv file and the column names or column headers had spaces between the words instead of underscores and I was originally trying to order the table in terms of release dates by typing this query:
SELECT * FROM `loyal-throne-393901.movie_data.movies` ORDER BY Release Date;
and it gave me a syntax error that said "syntax error: expected end of input but got keyword Date at [5:18]"
So, then I went back to my Excel spreadsheet and changed the column headers and included an underscore instead of just a space between the words and for some reason it accepted it, and it works? This was my query:
SELECT * FROM `loyal-throne-393901.movie_data.movies` ORDER BY Release_Date;
So, now my question is, why did SQL give me an syntax error for my first query but it accepted my second one? Any help or insight is appreciated, thank you.
